# React redux: Multiple actions with mapStatetoProps, and a common reducer

Tags: reactjs, api, redux, react-redux

How does mapStatetoProps receive multiple dispatch actions ?

I am dispatching multiple actions and connecting them with redux. But the problem is that the `this.props.pageData` mentioned in `mapStatetoProps` **only receives the data of the second action**.

```
function mapStateToProps(state){
  return {
      pageData: state.posts.arr
  };
};

function loadData(store){
  return Promise.all([
    store.dispatch(fetchNews() ),
    store.dispatch(fetchEvents() )
  ])
}

export default {
  loadData,
  component: connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchNews , fetchEvents})(HomePage)
};
```

And the **reducer** :

```
export default function(state = {
    posts: null
}, action){
    switch(action.type){
        case 'FETCH_POSTS': 
            return {...state, arr: action.payload || false};
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

The **actions** look like this (it is an API call) :

```
export const fetchNews = () => async (dispatch, getState, api) => {

    await api.get('/myAPI').then(response => {
        dispatch({
            type: 'FETCH_POSTS',
            payload: response.data
        })
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log('actions/index.js error', err);
    })

};
```

How do I map the actions as a particular prop name with mapStatetoProps?

Comment: You can assign the values to state with different property (e.g. Fetch post -> `return Object.assign({}, state, { post: {.. post data }});`  and get the same from `mapStatetoProps`.

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean @ShubhamKhatri. I have provided everything required, including the reducer.

Comment: @SelvaTS - You mean i should put this in 'FETCH_POSTS' in the reducer? and what changes do I make to mapStatetoProps then

Comment: I meant how does `fetchEvents` action looks like, are you calling FETCH_POSTS from there too

Comment: Yes update your reducer something like the above said, and in the `mapStatetoProps` update like this,  `return { post: state.posts.post, <other props>  };`

Comment: @ShivanshJagga, I have created a sample codesandbox with different props. https://codesandbox.io/s/jn5lx993v3

Comment: There is no object.assign in the codesandbox. I'm sorry , im new to this, so i guess its harder for me to understand.

Comment: @ShivanshJaggaI have updated the code. Please refer the updated sandbox.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so this is the work around I used, although this doesn't exactly answer the question asked :

```
function mapStateToProps(state){
  return {
      newsData: state.posts.news,
      eventsData: state.posts.events
  };
};
```

And in the **reducer** :

```
export default function(state = {
    posts: null
}, action){
    switch(action.type){
        case 'FETCH_NEWS': 
            return {...state, news: action.payload || false};
        case 'FETCH_EVENTS': 
            return {...state, events: action.payload || false};
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```